# Need help displaying float into printf

Tags: c

I was testing coding on float and displaying them in print in a singular function, after getting that to work, I changed it into modular but one of the float numbers i input does not display (e.g. input is 2.4, shows the 4 part but not the 2).

here's my code for what im working on

```
#include <stdio.h>


int calculate (float change, int dollar, int cents)
{
    scanf ("%f", &change);

    dollar = (int) change;
    cents = (int) (((change - dollar) * 100) + 0.5);

    return (dollar, cents);
}

int display (int dollar, int cents)
{
    printf("dollar is %d\n", dollar);
    printf("cents is %d", cents);

    return (0);
}

int main ()
{
    float change;
    int dollar, cents;

    dollar = (int) change;
    cents = calculate(change, dollar, cents);

    display (dollar, cents);

    return (0);
}
```

** Its not displaying dollar in printf, all i get is 0 **

Comment: `return (dollar, cents);` does not do what you think it does - you can only `return` a single value from a function, you need to use pointers as "out parameters"

Comment: @UnholySheep
right i did not know that. or i must have missed that information. thanks!

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your code to get no warnings. Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program. Improve it. Repeat till satisfied. Regarding floats, read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointer to get the value for the variable.

```
cents = calculate(change, &dollar, &cents);
```

Here dollar and cents are being passed with the address for the value to be accessible in main function.

```
int calculate (float change, int* dollar, int* cents)
{
    scanf ("%f", &change);

    *dollar = (int) change;
    *cents = (int) (((change - *dollar) * 100) + 0.5);

    return (*dollar, *cents);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I'd leave the function returning anything, the code would be very confusing in a shared code base.

Comment: @arun i managed to get it to work by using your example so its a lot of help. Im still new to c programming and sometimes cant get around it (like pass by value? or is it reference?

by doing this

`int calculate (float change, int* dollar, int cents)
{
    scanf ("%f", &change);

    *dollar = (int) change;
    cents = (int) (((change - *dollar) * 100) + 0.5);`


and in my main

`int main ()
{
    float change;
    int dollar, cents;

    dollar = (int) change;
    cents = calculate(change, &dollar, cents);

    display (dollar, cents);

    return (0);
}`

Comment: sorry for messy look, i dunno how to print my code neatly lol.

Comment: the example i gave is call by reference. I am passing the address(reference) of dollar and cents.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `return (dollar, cents);` is using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) (so returns `cents`).

If you want `calculate` to return *two* values you should declare a `struct` like

```
struct monetarytwoints_st {
  int mon_dollars;
  int mon_cents;
};
```

and have `calculate` return that type, so code something like

```
struct monetarytwoints_st calculate(float change) {
   int doll, cnts;
   doll = (int) change;
   cnts = (int) (((change - doll) * 100) + 0.5);
   return (struct monetarytwoints_st) { doll, cnts };
}
```

you probably should do input in one function, and computation in another one. Calling `scanf` from `calculate` is very bad taste.

BTW, return a small `struct` of two numbers is very efficient on x86-64; the [x86-64 ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) says that two registers are used for returning such a small `struct`.

Be aware that C uses a [call-by-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) argument passing, so any change of some formal arguments in a called function does not affect the actual arguments at the call site in the calling statement.

Comment: We don't learn struct in my school i dont think, its in the curriculum so i wouldn't understand, but thanks!